# Problem making a GET request and spoof User-Agent in urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

With this code, urllib2 make a GET request:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.fr')
req.add_header('User-Agent', '')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

With this one (which is almost the same), a POST request:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
headers = { 'User-Agent' : '' }
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.fr', '', headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

My question is: how can i make a GET request with the second code style ?

The documentation (http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/urllib2.html) says that

> headers should be a dictionary, and
>   will be treated as if add_header() was
>   called with each key and value as
>   arguments

Yeah, except that in order to use the *headers* parameter, you have to pass *data*, and when data is passed, the request become a POST.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: @bibop554, I recommend you take a look at `httplib2` much more easy to handle then `urllib2`. http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.fr', None, headers)
```

or:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.fr', headers=headers)
```